# Recursive function never return my temp array

Tags: php, recursion, return

I'm assuming my loop keeps looping and clearing my temp array, but not sure how to fix this. At the end, return is always empty.

How can I correctly return my `temp` array?

Data set:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [id] => 55
                    [parent] => 49
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [id] => 62
                    [parent] => 50
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [id] => 64
                    [parent] => 51
                )
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [id] => 49
                    [parent] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

Function:

```
<?php

    $patterns = function($array, $temp = array(), $index = 0, $parent = 0) use(&$patterns) {
        if($index < count($array)) {
            foreach($array[$index] as $sub) {
                if($index == 0 || $parent == $sub['id']) {
                    $temp[$index] = $sub['id'];
                    $patterns($array, $temp, $index + 1, $sub['parent']);
                }
            }
        }

        if($index >= count($array) && $parent == 0) {
            print_r($temp); // correct result does display here!

            return $temp; // this return gives no return
        }
    };

    print_r($patterns($dataset));

?>
```

`print_r` returns `Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 49 )`

Comment: expected output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 8, return the result of `$patterns($array, $temp, ...)` only if it is not null. Also, don't set the result to the `$temp` variable, so you don't override it if the result is null.

Like so:

```
$temp2 = $patterns($array, $temp, $index + 1, $sub['parent']);

if (isset($temp2)) {
    return $temp2;
}
```

If the condition on line 13 fails, it'll return null, and that's not the result you want, so you have to keep going if it is null.

---

By the way, I wasn't able to reproduce your code giving the correct answer where it says `// correct result does display here!`. To make it work I had to change lines 5 & 6 to:

```
foreach($array[$index] as $key => $sub) {
    if ($key == 0 || $parent == $sub['id']) {
```

And I also had to change line 13 to:

```
if($index >= count($array)-1 && $parent == 0) {
```

Comment: thank you so much! Line 5, 6, and 13 changes broke the logic. The returning the variable worked!

Comment: Ah just realized that my datA set is already reversed so no need to reverse again. This is the reason you couldn't get the result. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you modify line #6 and add "return" to the beginning of it?

```
    RETURN $patterns($array, $temp, $index + 1, $sub['parent']);
```

Comment: Actually, I see something.  Your line "return $temp" isn't inside any function that I can see.  It's outside of the $patterns function.  Your value of $temp is set at that point - but there's nowhere to "return" it to.  Is that it?